# how can I insert a condition "if it contains" to search for a specific letter in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, count, conditional-statements

I want to count how many times appear the parameters CA, CU and CH, in an excel that looks like this:

[image]

I have tried to use the following code, but as the cells don't contain only the parameter I am searching for, it doesn't work:

```
Sub ContarOV()

    Dim cont As Variant
    Dim sumaCA As Variant
    Dim sumaCU As Variant
    Dim sumaCH As Variant

    sumaCA = 0
    sumaCU = 0
    sumaCH = 0

    For cont = 3 To 12
        If Cells(cont, 2) = ("CA") Then
            sumaCA = sumaCA + 1
        End If
        If Cells(cont, 2) = ("CU") Then
             sumaCU = sumaCU + 1
        End If
        If Cells(cont, 2) = ("CH") Then
            sumaCH = sumaCH + 1
        End If
    Next cont

End Sub
```

Comment: ```instr()``` is what you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Comment: Just use `CountIf` with wildcards. No need to loop here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @BigBen, I would try to avoid any iteration. What about one of the following options (assuming your data sits from `A2:A?`):

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long
Dim arr As Variant
Dim rng As Range

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Get last used row
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Get data into memory for method 1
    arr = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A" & lr).Value)

    'Create range object for method 2
    Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & lr)

    'Method 1: Count values with FILTER
    Debug.Print UBound(Filter(arr, "CA")) + 1
    Debug.Print UBound(Filter(arr, "CU")) + 1
    Debug.Print UBound(Filter(arr, "CH")) + 1

    'Method 2: Count values with COUNTIF
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "CA*")
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "CU*")
    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "CH*")

End With

End Sub
```

Btw, I would give `sumaCA` and your other variables a meaningfull data type, `Long` in this case.

Comment: `Filter` is a great option.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, I've never really used this before and allthough the versatility is limited I do think it's still a strong tool in some occasions.

Comment: @xabi I did not write it, it was JvdV - please make sure to accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `InStr()` to return the position of the desired characters in the string. This would look something like `If Not InStr(1, Cells(cont,2).Text, "CH") = 0 Then`, but looping through strings is generally a slow process. Unless you have a specific need for looping, I like BigBen's answer a lot better than I like looping with `InStr()`.

Comment: All credit goes to @JvdV, I did not write the answer.